# Is there some standard name for this particular order of terms in an elementary symmetric polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, order-theory, symmetric-functions

The elementary symmetric polynomial $e_{n,k}$ in variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is the sum of all products of $k$ of those $n$ variables, thus:
$$
e_{n,k} = \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} A \, \subseteq\, \{1,\ldots,n\} \\ |A| \, =\, k \end{smallmatrix}} \prod_{j\,\in\, A} x_j.
$$
Now suppose I want to speak of putting the terms in a particular order, here exemplified by $e_{6,3}:$

\begin{align}
e_{6,3} = {} \qquad& x_1 x_2 x_3 & & \text{max index} = 3 \\[10pt]
{}+{} & \underbrace{\overbrace{x_1 x_2 x_4}^{\text{max}\,=\,2} + x_1 x_3 x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4}_{\text{max} = 3} & & \text{max index} = 4 \\[10pt]
{}+{} & \underbrace{\underbrace{\overbrace{x_1 x_2 x_5}^{\text{max} = 2} + x_1 x_3 x_5 + x_2 x_3 x_5}_{\text{max} = 3} + x_1 x_4 x_5 + x_2 x_4 x_5 + x_3 x_4 x_5}_{\text{max}=4} & & \text{max index} = 5 \\[10pt]
{} + {} & \overbrace{\overbrace{\overbrace{x_1 x_2 x_6}^{\text{max}=2} {} + x_1 x_3 x_6 + x_2 x_3 x_6}^{\text{max}=3}  {} + x_1 x_4 x_6 + x_2 x_4 x_6 + x_3 x_4 x_6}^{\text{max}=4} \\
& {} + x_1 x_5 x_6 + x_2 x_5 x_6 + x_3 x_5 x_6 + x_4 x_ 5 x_6 & & \text{max index} = 6
\end{align}

First we have the terms in which the maximum index is 3, then 4, then 5 then 6.

**Within** each of those, we first have the ones with maximum second-largest index 2, then (where applicable) 3, then (where applicable) 4, etc.

**Within** those, the third-largest index increases step by step.

And so on.

I thought "lexicographic order", and then immediately noticed that that is *not* what this is; for example, $x_3 x_4 x_5$ comes before $x_1 x_2 x_6$. And notice that if we were ordering the terms of $e_{7,3},$ then all of the above would come immediately before $x_1 x_2 x_7,$ so that $x_4 x_5 x_6$ comes before $x_1 x_2 x_7.$

**So my question is:** Is there some standard name for this order?

**Unlike lexicographic order,** this order has the property that if you add another variable (in this case $x_7$), the additional terms all come after the ones you've already got.

Comment: Why do you think this is not the lexicographic order ??

Comment: @user1952009 : Because, to name just one example, $x_1 x_3 x_4$ comes before $x_1 x_2 x_5. \qquad$

Comment: @user1952009 : . . . . . and $x_3 x_4 x_5$ comes before $x_1 x_2 x_6. \qquad$

Comment: come on ${}{}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 : Your meaning escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [colexicographic order](https://oeis.org/wiki/Orderings#Colexicographic_order). Same example even.